# Seeking information about USGS Quadrangles dating back 1945?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I work for the US Forest Service and on my forest we have Map cabinet that has all the hardcopies (not digitial) USGS quadrangle that has years on them such as 1954, 1968 to now. The map cabinet is on our office and we will have more at another building that I am going through...

What I am trying to find information from these dates should I find online ?

Do you have the information that may be very helpful to me ?

I am working on map inventory to the Excel spreadsheet

Comment: what kind of information are you trying to find?

Comment: Just pulled out the information for each quad. I am aware that the USGS has their own on their online but I am not sure if they have the olden ones that goes back to 1940's

Comment: So what you're actually looking for is: an online source of *old* (1940-1990) USGS quadrangle maps. Correct?

Comment: Yes. The USGS has their online here: https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/advanced-viewer/    but the problem that they are up to now and some of them in the old days do not have it there.. like Mt. Lincoln from 1938 isn't even there...

Comment: So I need to know where Mt. Lincoln is and it could be replaced with another name of another quad ...